# How to add/set start date and end date field defaults to the first day of the report period

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi i am creating a ssrs report and i want to set start and end date set to default first day and last day of the month respectively. How can i do that one?
here is the condition 
The start date field defaults to the first day of the report period.
The end date field defaults to the last day of the report period.

can anyone help with this condition?

Answer (score 1):

First day of the month expression

```
=system.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1-system.DateTime.Today.Day)
```

Last day of the month expression

```
=system.DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-system.DateTime.Today.Day)
```

Comment: Hi it is displaying first day from your first expression and what i also need to display the month also as first like 1/1/2019. is that possible?

Comment: you can use `system.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1-system.DateTime.Today.DayOfYear)` or `=system.DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(system.DateTime.Today.Year-1)`